# Python: Lib which provides FTP-Server on localhost in ContextManager

Tags: python, software-testing, ftp

I would like to test code which connects to a ftp server as clients and up- and downloads files.

Is there a Python library which provides a context manager which runs a ftp server on localhost (port 2121)?

I would like the usage of this library look roughly like this:

```
def test_my_ftp_foo(self):
    with ftp_server_context(user='myuser', password='mypassword', port=2121):
        with ftputil.FTPHost(host='localhost', 'myuser', 'mypassword', port=2121) as host:
            host.makedirs('a/b')
            host.chrdir(...')
            ...
```

I see several ways to implement this library.

One would be to use subprocess.Popen() and run a script using pyftpdlib until `__exit__()` tells the context manager to kill the ftp server.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384833/temporary-ftp-server-for-testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple library which provides what I was looking for:

https://github.com/tbz-pariv/ftpservercontext

> FTP server context manager for testing ftp client code

Answer (score 0):

You can start an FTP server from the command line by using the twisted python framework.

Once you have installed twisted, *and possibly pywin32,* with pip you can start an ftp server from the command line, (or using popen).

The command to start one is:

```
python -m twisted ftp
```

You can specify authorization, port, root directory, etc. *note that this is **not** a production grade FTP server*